# How to map list items with their tail [Scala]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

How does one map each item in a list iteratively with it's remaining tail? Pseudo code example:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4) 
list.foreach((head, tail) => println(s"head= $head, tail= $tail")) 
// head= 1, tail = List(2, 3, 4) 
// head= 2, tail = List(3, 4) 
// head= 3, tail = List(4) 
// head= 4, tail = List()
```

Comment: Pattern matching with `@tailrec`? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Maybe `tails`? As I always say the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#tails:Iterator[C]) is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way seems to be the good old `for`-loop, which has the advantage that it inserts a filtering step for you, so you don't crash on the `Nil` case while iterating over the tails:

```
for (h :: t <- (1 to 4).toList.tails) println(s"head: $h tail: $t")
```

gives:

```
head: 1 tail: List(2, 3, 4)
head: 2 tail: List(3, 4)
head: 3 tail: List(4)
head: 4 tail: List()
```

If you don't actually need the `println`-side effect, a `for-yield` would give you just the values.

Answer (score 2):

```
def rec(l: List[Int]) : Unit = {
    l match {
        case head::tail => println(s"head= $head, tail= $tail")
            rec(tail)
        case _ =>
    }
}

scala> rec(l)
    head= 1, tail= List(2, 3, 4)
    head= 2, tail= List(3, 4)
    head= 3, tail= List(4)
    head= 4, tail= List()
```

Answer (score 0):

A (to me) more straightforward answer. As @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez says, tails is your friend

```
(xs zip xs.tails.toList) map {case (h, t) => println("Head: " + h + " Tail: " + t)}
```

The .toList is a pity, though

---